# A way round the need to verify domain before creating a bucket in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

A month or so ago I put up a static website using google cloud storage. Before I could create a public bucket, I was asked to verify that I actually owned the domain after which I was naming the bucket. I had to upload a file from google to the existing host in order for google to verify domain ownership.

I do understand the need to do this. However, if I had just bought a domain and had no other host, I don't see how I would have been able to prove that I owned the domain.

Did I miss a way around this limitation? Is there another, more user friendly way of creating public sites on google cloud storage?

Comment: sorry for the title typo: s/A way round/a way around/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways to verify domain ownership:

1. Adding a special Meta tag to a site's homepage.
2. Uploading a special HTML file to a site.
3. Adding a DNS TXT record to a domain's DNS configuration.

The first two require the domain to be hosted somewhere but the third method is purely DNS configuration, so it can be accomplished without hosting the domain. You can read more details about these methods [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming#verification).

Answer (score 0):

Add CName with the information that the google gives you. That would solve your problem of verifying your domain ownership.